# Tomcat gives a 404 when using Jersey on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I'm following this tutorial https://www.javatpoint.com/jax-rs-example-jersey using Eclipse's Dynamic Web Project. The index page works fine, but the jersey part gives a 404. I tried the following urls:

```
http://localhost:8080/JerseyProject/rest/hello
http://localhost:8080/JerseyProject/hello
```

Both don't work. This is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: What does the Console mention about your project while the app server is starting?

Comment: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer"

Comment: That's a pretty fundamental problem. Does the tutorial match the Jersey version you're using?

Comment: Where are your Jersey libraries? If you're not using Maven, you should put all the libraries into the webapp/WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: @nitind I used the same jars mentioned in the tutorial, not sure if this is what you mean...